# Voicemail app that doesn't require carrier voicemail

Tags: applications, calls, voicemail

I'm looking for a voicemail app that will answer my phone after a configurable number of rings and route the caller to voicemail stored on the Android device.

I don't have voicemail with my carrier.

I'm not interested in features of Google Voice because it seems to piggyback on real voicemail and also I don't want to port my phone number to another service if indeed that is required.

(Note: I remember doing something similar on a PC desktop years ago when the phone line was hooked into the modem, the computer would act as voicemail.)

Comment: Google voice doesn't piggy back on real voicemail, it replaces it.

Comment: Reference material from G+ https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnKaneD/posts/1NT3gSj78QK

Answer (score 1):

Try if any of these [apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=call-recorder&c=apps) work for you. It would depend on your phone, as android has limited support for total offline answering machine capabilities due to technical barriers. See [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=16625632) on XDA. If your phone isn't compatible, you might have the following issues:

- Not be able to record calls
- Record the conversation at only one end
- Very low sound quality or volume

Google voice doesn't depend on your voicemail. The calls are recorded on google voice's servers.

Answer (score 0):

Youmail and PF Voicemail+ are the two apps that come close to your requirement. please try. youmail has lot of options and features. There is one more "hullomail smart voicemail".

After going through many posts, youmail has been voted highly by users. PF voicemail + offers you transcripts of those voicemail but you have to check if there are any charges.

- [YouMail Voicemail & Call Blocker | Apps in Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youmail.android.vvm)
- [HulloMail Smart Voicemail | Apps in Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hullomail.messaging.android)

Please note that some of these apps will require you to do the forwarding to their servers.

It also depends on where you are located and mobile you are using. Can you mention what type of mobile you are using? It will help in knowing whether there are any limitations involved.